# Writing a function to enclose another function with regression models

Tags: r, function

Goal: Run three regression models with three different outcome variables, as seen below, but ideally in a more efficient way than seen in the model1, model2, model3 version seen in the last three lines.

Specific question: How can I write a function that iterates over the set of dv's and creates model + # indicator as an object (e.g. model1, model2, etc.) AND switches the dv (e.g. dv1, dv2, etc...)? I assume there is a forloop and function solution to this but I am not getting it...

```
mydf <- data.frame(dv1 = rnorm(100),
               dv2 = rnorm(100),
               dv3 = rnorm(100),
               iv1 = rnorm(100),
               iv2 = rnorm(100),
               iv3 = rnorm(100))

mymodel <- function(dv, df) {
lm(dv ~ iv1 + iv2 + iv3, data = df)
}

model1 <- mymodel(dv = mydf$dv1, df = mydf)
model2 <- mymodel(dv = mydf$dv2, df = mydf)
model3 <- mymodel(dv = mydf$dv3, df = mydf)
```

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-create-a-loop-to-run-multiple-regression-models/

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach using the `tidyverse` packages, since `dplyr` has more or less supplanted `plyr`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mydf <- data.frame(dv1 = rnorm(100),
                   dv2 = rnorm(100),
                   dv3 = rnorm(100),
                   iv1 = rnorm(100),
                   iv2 = rnorm(100),
                   iv3 = rnorm(100))

mymodel <- function(df) {
  lm(value ~ iv1 + iv2 + iv3, data = df)
}

mydf %>% 
  gather("variable","value", contains("dv")) %>% 
  split(.$variable) %>% 
  map(mymodel) 

#> $dv1
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = value ~ iv1 + iv2 + iv3, data = df)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)          iv1          iv2          iv3  
#>    -0.04516     -0.04657      0.08045      0.02518  
#> 
#> 
#> $dv2
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = value ~ iv1 + iv2 + iv3, data = df)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)          iv1          iv2          iv3  
#>    -0.03906      0.16730      0.10324      0.02500  
#> 
#> 
#> $dv3
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = value ~ iv1 + iv2 + iv3, data = df)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)          iv1          iv2          iv3  
#>    0.018492    -0.162563     0.002738     0.179366
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your data.frame to long form, with all the dv values in one column and then use `plyr`'s `dlply` to create the lms. This splits the data.frame on the specified column ("dvN") and applys the function to each and returns a list of lms. I have changed the function slightly to make it just take a data.frame, not the column separately.

Hope this gives what you need.

```
library(plyr)
library(tidyr)

mydf_l <- gather(mydf, dvN, Value, 1:3)

mymodel2 <- function(df) {
  lm(Value ~ iv1 + iv2 + iv3, data = df)
}

allmodels <- dlply(mydf_l, .(dvN), mymodel2)
```